# Forming a recursive equation from a function

Tags: algorithm, recursion, big-o

I've been asked to form a recurrence equation from a recursive function and solve it for T(n). This function  divides an array of  elements into two halves; find the highest value of each half, then returns the highest of the two. However I am having some trouble understanding how to form a recurrence equation from this function.

I've looked at some similar questions here and elsewhere on the internet, and from what I think I've understood, this function does two recursive calls and splits the data into 2 each time, and size should be = n, however I am unsure regarding the other elements in the function and how to write them correctly.

```
ℎ([], , )
{  
  ( == 1)  
  A[];  

  1 = ℎMax([], , ⌊/2⌋); 
  2 = ℎMax([],  + ⌊/2⌋,  − ⌊/2⌋); 

  if (1 ≥ 2)  
   1;  
    
   2;  
}
```

Comment: Using English names for variables and types would probably help to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

T(n) = 2T(n/2) + c

Time complexity - O(n)

The function makes 2 recursive calls on sub arrays of size n/2 and a constant work